# Training the autoencoder with identical images

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am training the autoencoder with 2000 **identical** images. My expectation is, that given the autoencoder has enough capacity the loss will approach 0 and the accuracy will approach 1 after a certain training time. Instead I see a quick convergence to loss = 0.07 and accuracy=0.76. Reducing the number of convolutional layers gave some improvement. Reducing the number of kernels per layer increased the loss. There is no improvement after that. Is my expectation wrong? Or is there something wrong with my autoencoder architecture? What can be done to make an almost lossless autoencoder?

```
input_img = Input(shape=(image_size_x, image_size_y, 1))
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a dense layer for the latent representation?

Comment: @ Dr. H. Lecter: No, I don't have a dense layer. Why is it needed and how would you integrate a dense layer into the autoencoder? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The latent_dim will depend on the type of images, size etc. On the MNIST dataset you can ahve a latent_dim of 2 but this is extreme for standard images.

Comment: Does the answer help? let me know

Comment: @ Dr. H. Lecter: Thanks a lot for your quick response! Currently trying to implement. Will give you feedback, as soon as I will get it working.

Comment: @ Dr. H. Lecter: Do I need a Reshape Layer in the decoder part? Somehow I am getting an error:  Layer conv2d_3 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.layers.core.Dense'>.

Comment: For the decoder input you need to use the latent_dim as input and you will need to add a reshape layer yes something smilar to this:

tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(latent_dim,)),tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=7*7*32, activation=tf.nn.relu),
tf.keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(7, 7, 32)),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a dense layer between your autoconvolutional encoder and autoconvolution decoder. This is the latent reprensentation, also called embedding layer. This is the layer in which the image is compressed. That is the "compressed knowledge"  that the architecture is trying to "learn".

For the implementation, from this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cvae
I would suggest you add these lines between the encoder and the decoder part:

```
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x),
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(latent_dim + latent_dim)
```